# PyQuery won't return elements on a page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyquery

I've set up a Python script to open this web page with `PyQuery`.

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery

url = "http://www.floridaleagueofcities.com/widgets/cityofficials?CityID=101"
page = requests.get(url)
pqPage = PyQuery(page.content)
```

But `pqPage("li")` returns only a blank list, `[]`. Meanwhile, `pqPage.text()` shows the text of the page's HTML, which includes `li` elements.

Why won't the code return a list of `li` elements? How do I make it do that?

Comment: Have you tried the find filter to get the 'li' elements?

Comment: @Vishal Yes. Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In seems `PyQuery` has problem to work with this page - maybe because it is `xhtml` page. Or maybe because it use namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

When I use

```
pqPage.css('li')
```

then I get

```
[<{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html#sfFrontendHtml>]
```

which shows `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}` in element - it is `namespace`. Some modules has problem with `HTML` which uses namespaces.

---

I have no problem to get it using `Beautifulsoup`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "http://www.floridaleagueofcities.com/widgets/cityofficials?CityID=101"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BS(page.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('li'):
    print(item.text)
```

---

**EDIT:** after digging in Google I found that using `parser="html"` in `PyQuery()` I can get `li`.

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery

url = "http://www.floridaleagueofcities.com/widgets/cityofficials?CityID=101"
page = requests.get(url)

pqPage = PyQuery(page.text, parser="html")
for item in pqPage('li p'):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: The BS4 solution works. Can PyQuery parse this page?

Comment: I found that using `parser="html"` I can get it. See new code in answer.